# Pass PHP Variable into Java Script window.location

Tags: php, javascript, window.location

I am trying to pass a php variable into a java script window.location that returns a user to the current list view after deleting an item from the database. I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Code:

```
function confirmation(a) {
var currString = "<? echo $currString ?>";
var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
if (answer){
    alert("The item has been deleted")
    window.location = "list.php?s='. $currString .'&=delete=true&id=" + a;
}
else{
    alert("The item has not been deleted")
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
function confirmation(a) {
    var currString = "<?php echo $currString ?>";
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
    if (answer){
        alert("The item has been deleted")
        window.location = "list.php?s=" + currString + "&=delete=true&id=" + a;
    }
    else{
        alert("The item has not been deleted");
}
```

Comment: Yaw, the concatenation operator is mixed up. As well as misplacing quotes.

Comment: It seems the code fails to open the alert window. My delete button does nothing.

Comment: Sorry it does work. It was missing/needed an additional "}". I failed to copy that the first time.

Comment: One last question. Now the alert is working but it doesn't actually delete the entry from the database. This function was working...if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM resources WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1");
 }

Comment: sorry man, no idea! But the request is made right? Maybe some problem with server side. No idea about that right now. :)

Comment: Got it: "DELETE FROM resources WHERE parent_category LIKE '%$currString%' AND id = $id LIMIT 1"

Comment: you are missing a ; after the confirm() and first alert()

Comment: ok! corrected!......man! that's an observation! That's real observation! I answered this on 20th June, and you are the first one to find this mistake - 8th August! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

you are pasing php variable to JS variable
    var currString = "";

and in `window.location` you are passing again php variable which is wrong,

so do it like this

```
window.location = "list.php?s=" + currString + "&=delete=true&id=" + a;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax issue was solved by other answers, but you need to take care of an additional issue: [URI encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) your variable when you use it in the URL:

```
window.location = "list.php?s="
                + encodeURIComponent(currString)
                + "&=delete=true&id=" + a;
```

or else you will run into problems of your variable contains characters like `&`.

Answer (score -3):

```
echo "<script>alert('System info has been Save')</script>";
echo "<script>window.location='customer_detail.php?
customer_id=".$customer_id."'</script>";
```

Comment: This has typos in the code, you are missing two ; in the echoed javascript