# Get php variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm writing mostly in PHP, but one function requires me to use JavaScript. I need to access a PHP variable in my JavaScript. I've placed the following code between the `<head>` tags:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {
            if ($('.pho_big').is(':visible') && e.keyCode==27) { 
                var js_link = '<?php echo $p_link; ?>';
                window.location.href = js_link;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In short, when the esc key is pressed, I want to go to `$p_link`. So I'm trying to copy `$p_link` to js_link and go there. Instead of getting the contents of `$p_link`, my browser is trying to go to `<?php%20echo($p_link)%20?>`, which is obviously incorrect.

I've already gone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122696/pass-php-variable-into-java-script-window-location), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415868/get-variable-from-php-to-javascript), all of which seem to tell me to do exactly what I'm doing. My knowledge of JavaScript is near zero, so I'm probably missing something simple, but I don't know enough to know what or troubleshoot.

Comment: It appears that `$p_link` is an empty string or something that echos to that. Also please note that the way your doing it PHP is creating JavaScript on page load and so JavaScript will have a hard value of what `$p_link` is at the time of the page render and not when the they key is pressed. If it's an echo problem try `var_dump`ing it

Comment: After your edit, if your getting the literal tags in your JavaScript that means it's not actually not passing through PHP, probably because you ended your file in `.js` and not `.php`

Comment: in the (external) php file, $p_link is nothing more than a string of characters, with the occasional . and /

The code I pasted is in a .tpl file (header.tpl), which is referenced in a .php file. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Anything that doesn't end in `.php` will not be interpreted. Also `include` and `require` can be thought of you just copying and pasting them inline into your file (from what I remember).

Comment: I've used include with my php code, but I don't understand how it would help here. If I used it to paste my php variable in the JavaScript, you're telling me it still wouldn't intepret. And if I could simply handle the keystroke in my php code, I would. Either way, I think I only need one or two lines, not an entire file.

Comment: Basically your code is good, it's just not being processed by PHP which is most likey caused by this file not ending in `.php`.

Comment: The only reason you would use include is if your where trying to process a file that is __not__ ending in `.php`.

Comment: I just tried pasting the code at the top of my php file instead, and that seems to do the trick! Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: No problem, things can be tricky when you start.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like `<?php echo $p_link; ?>` is not interpreted by php.so `js_link` contains string `<?php echo $p_link; ?>`.when you set `window.location.href` to  `<?php echo $p_link; ?>` . browser tries to go to `[less_than]?php%20echo($p_link)%20?[greater_than]` which is url encoding of `<?php echo $p_link; ?>`.

(sorry,since I have low reputation, I cant post comment)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening, only with the actual [greater_than] tags in the url (I couldn't figure out how to make them appear normally here). WHY is that happening?

Comment: like @justGage told. your file might be ending with html or js extension.So php interpreter didn't had a chance to interpret it .check that file extension.

Comment: you can create a variable like `<script>window.Js_link="<?php echo $p_link; ?>";</script>`, somewhere in your php file (before including header.tpl) and    use       `window.location.href=window.js_link;` inside the event handling function.